# IS_Numeric and Get

Tags: php

When I enter a value it should be numeric only. In my code the check seems to be false because I can enter several non numeric items.
Do you have an idea ?

```
<body>
  <form method="GET" action="">
    <input type="text" name="niveau">
    <input type="submit" value="valider" >

  </form>
  <br />
  <?php 

  if (empty($_GET['niveau'])) 
  {
    echo 'Enter niveau please : ' . "</br>";
  }

  else if(isset($_GET['niveau'])) 
  {
    echo "Niveau : " .$_GET['niveau'] . "</br>";

  }

  else if (is_numeric($_GET['niveau']))
  {
    echo "Niveau is numeric" ;
  }

  else
  {
    echo "$var_name1 is not numeric. <br>" ;
  }

  ?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `if/else if` structure. The first else if checks whether or not the niveau parameter is set. If yes you print out the niveau level and the second else if condition won't be checked. 
You could for example include the second `else if` condition within the first one, something like this:

```
  if (empty($_GET['niveau'])) 
  {
    echo 'Enter niveau please : ' . "</br>";
  }

  else if(isset($_GET['niveau']) && is_numeric($_GET['niveau'])) 
  {
    echo "Niveau : " .$_GET['niveau'] . "</br>";

  }    

  else
  {
    echo "$var_name1 not set or not numeric. <br>" ;
  }
```